# how to display the properties of a table when there is an intermediate table between it?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am new to programming and I have a problem displaying the properties of one of my table knowing that there is an intermediate table I did the route like this in my nodejs:

```js
router.get('/ getById /: id', (req, res) => {
  db.annonce
    .findAll({
      where: { id: req.params.id },
      include: [{ model: db.adherent }]
    })
    .then(announcement => {
      res.status(200).json({ announcement: announcement });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

and to display it on vuejs I did this (everything passes except my h3 which is not displayed):

```html
<div class="card" v-for="advertisement in adverts" : key="advertisement.id">
  <div class="cartecorps">
    <h3>{{announcement.Adherents.Firstname}}</h3>

    <div class="firstline">
      <p>
        <i class="fas fa-dumbbell"> </i> Training partner for the
        <span> {{announcement.davailability}} </span>
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> </i> {{announcement.Ville}}
      </p>
      <p><i class="far fa-clock"> </i> {{announcement.Time}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="secondline">
      <p>{{announcement.Your_Waiting}}</p>
      <button>Reply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: isn't this `announcement` coming from loop?

Answer (score 1):

Good that at least something does work ;).

When you open your developer tools panel in your browser, you'll find a network tab. In that you'll find your request. When you click on it, you can see the response. Could you show us the response? Since we cannot help you properly right now. It may be the case that your announcements object does not contain your "Adherents" object. Maybe it should be "adherents" or adherent?
I suspect that in that case you also will get an error in your console panel.

Now, you could also install the [vuejs devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) to get more debugging info.